# WebScrape - Pagination/Next page

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination, css-selectors

The current code works and scrapes the page how I want it to.

However, how can I get this to run for the next page ? The URL is not unique for the second page and I want to run for all pages.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
lists=[]

r = requests.get('https://journals.lww.com/ccmjournal/toc/2022/01001')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
d = {i.text.strip():i['href'] for i in soup.select('.ej-toc-subheader + div h4 > a')}
lists.append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a dynamically loaded webpage you need to use selenium for that. Have a look  here : [Selenium with Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)